# HTML email two column issue

Tags: html, css, email, html-table, html-email

I am trying to build a two column layout for a newsletter, but for some reason my columns are sometimes vertically aligning to the centre?

In some versions of outlook it works but others not?

Any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" />
<title>EMAIL NEWSLETTER</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%!important;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%!important;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased!important
}
img {
 border: 0!important;
 outline: none!important;
}
p {
 margin: 0!important;
 padding: 0!important;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 mso-table-lspace: 0;
 mso-table-rspace: 0;
}
td, a, span {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
}
.ExternalClass * {
 line-height: 100%;
}
span.MsoHyperlink {
 mso-style-priority: 99;
 color: inherit
}
span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed {
 mso-style-priority: 99;
 color: inherit;
}
.em_white a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.em_white_und a {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.em_orange a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #EC8026;
}
.em_orange1 a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #e44c16;
}
.em_marun a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #1e8faa;
}
.em_marun1 a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #1E8FAA;
}
.em_yellow a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #f5ebd7;
}
@media screen and (min-width:601px) {
.container {
 width: 600px!important;
}
}

</style>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<style type="text/css">table{border-collapse:collapse!important!important}</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
<table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><table class="container" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;">
        <tr>
          <td><table style="max-width:600px" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><![endif]-->
                  
                  <table class="container" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;" bgcolor="#1E8FAA">
                    <tr>
                      <td bgcolor="#1E8FAA" valign="top" style="border-spacing:0;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:582px"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td valign="top"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="582" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><![endif]-->
                              
                              <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="max-width:582px" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                  <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td height="20" style="line-height:0px;font-size:0px">&nbsp;</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td class="two-column" valign="top" style="text-align:left;font-size:0" dir="rtl"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%" dir="rtl"><tr><td width="188"><![endif]-->
                                          
                                          <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:188px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;text-align:left" dir="ltr">
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="column">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td valign="top" class="em_hide"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:198px;" cellpadding="0" align="right" class="column">
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                                                          <tr>
                                                            <td><table style="max-width:198px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left" class="column">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                  <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                  <td mc:edit="text_2" class="em_center" height="42" valign="middle" align="left" style="font-family:NewsGothicMT, 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px; line-height:15px; color:#ffffff;background-color:#1E8FAA;"><multiline style="font-family:NewsGothicMT, 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:11px; line-height:15px; color:#ffffff;background-color:#1E8FAA;"><span class="em_white">Email not displaying properly? </span></multiline>
                                                                    <br />
                                                                    <span class="em_white_und">
                                                                    <webversion style="text-decoration:underline;color:#ffffff;"><span class="em_white_und" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#ffffff;">View it in your browser.</span></webversion>
                                                                    </span></td>
                                                                  <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                              </table></td>
                                                          </tr>
                                                          <tr>
                                                            <td height="20" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                                          </tr>
                                                        </table></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </table></td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>
                                          </div>
                                          
                                          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td width="384"><![endif]-->
                                          
                                          <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:384px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;text-align:left" dir="ltr">
                                          <table width="100%" style="max-width:384px" cellpadding="0" align="center" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                              <tr>
                                                <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                    <tr>
                                                      <td width="10" class="em_hide">&nbsp;</td>
                                                      <td width="152" align="center" valign="top"><a href="http://www.website.org/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none"><img editable="true" src="/images/logo.jpg" width="152" alt="logo" style="display:block;font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;font-size:14px;color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;line-height:20px;max-width:152px;" border="0" /></a></td>
                                                      <td width="222" class="em_hide">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                  </table></td>
                                              </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td height="20" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px">&nbsp;</td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            
                                          </div>
                                          
                                          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                              
                              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                  
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 
<table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><repeater>
        
        <layout label="Gallery"> 
          
          <table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td align="center"><table class="container" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;">
                  <tr>
                    <td><table style="max-width:600px" width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <tr>
                          <td><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><![endif]-->
                            
                            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing:0;Margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:600px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                              <tr>
                                <td width="5" class="em_hide">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="two-column" valign="top" style="text-align:center;font-size:0"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%"><tr><td width="295"><![endif]-->
                                  
                                  <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:295px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;text-align:center">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="column">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td width="5" class="em_hide">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_side_space"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" valign="top"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img editable="true" src="http://placehold.it/350x250" width="285" alt="GALLERY ARTICLE 1" style="display:block;font-family:NewsGothicMT, 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px; line-height:30px; color:#000000;font-weight:bold;max-width:285px;" border="0" class="em_full_width" /></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td valign="top" bgcolor="#1E8FAA" style="background-color:#1E8FAA;"><table width="100%" style="max-width:285px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td height="15" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:NewsGothicMT, 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px; line-height:17px; color:#f5ebd7;"><span class="em_yellow">
                                                            <multiline style="font-family:NewsGothicMT, 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px; line-height:17px; color:#f5ebd7;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</multiline>
                                                            </span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td height="15" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </table></td>
                                                    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td height="18" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                        <td width="5" class="em_hide">&nbsp;</td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                  </div>
                                  
                                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td width="295"><![endif]-->
                                  
                                  <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:295px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;text-align:center">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="column">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td width="5" class="em_hide">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td align="center" valign="top" class="em_side_space"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                                            <tr>
                                              <td align="center" valign="top"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img editable="true" src="http://placehold.it/350x250" width="285" alt="GALLERY ARTICLE 2" style="display:block;font-family:NewsGothicMT, 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px; line-height:30px; color:#000000;font-weight:bold;max-width:285px;" border="0" class="em_full_width" /></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td valign="top" bgcolor="#1E8FAA" style="background-color:#1E8FAA;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                  <tr>
                                                    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td valign="top"><table width="100%" style="max-width:285px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td height="15" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:NewsGothicMT, 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px; line-height:17px; color:#f5ebd7;"><span class="em_yellow">
                                                            <multiline style="font-family:NewsGothicMT, 'Century Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;font-size:13px; line-height:17px; color:#f5ebd7;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</multiline>
                                                            </span></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                          <td height="15" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                      </table></td>
                                                    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                                  </tr>
                                                </table></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                              <td height="18" style="line-height:1px;font-size:1px;">&nbsp;</td>
                                            </tr>
                                          </table></td>
                                        <td width="5" class="em_hide">&nbsp;</td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                  </div>
                                  
                                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                                <td width="5" class="em_hide">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                            
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
           
        </layout>
        
      </repeater></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%"><tr><td width="295" valign="top"><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting a height for the element your trying to valign it should work.

Comment: thanks mmollle, but I think this would change every time as the amount of text in the caption would vary...or could I set it to auto perhaps?